# Is to ignore Satan also to underestimate the potential he has to assault the Christian?

Tags: satan

I've often thought that, once indwelt by the Holy Spirit and saved by the grace of God, Satan has nothing against me.

But, is to ignore Satan also to underestimate the potential he has to assault the Christian? What do the apostles and disciples of Christ say with respect to Satan's ability against the Christian?

Comment: Be cautious about Satan and his schemes but don't be afraid of him.

Comment: Not an answer, but you might want to check out C.S. Lewis's [The Screwtape Letters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Screwtape_Letters) to get a fictional perspective of Christianity from a Demon's point of view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we could ignore Satan knowing he has nothing against us, we wouldn't need to pay any attention to the scriptures that say

> Be sober, be vigilant; because your adversary the devil walks about
>   like a roaring lion, seeking whom he may devour. 1Pe 5:8
>
> The night is far spent, the day is at hand. Therefore let us cast off
>   the works of darkness, and let us put on the armor of light. Rom 13:12
>
> Resist the devil and he will flee from you. Jam 4:7
>
> above all, taking the shield of faith with which you will be able to
>   quench all the fiery darts of the wicked one. Eph 6:16

All these verses suggest that Satan's threats are as real as his potential for harm. Our fight against the enemy does not end until he is cast into darkness with Death (Rev 20:14).

Comment: how do we cast the enemy into darkness with death ?? Thank You,

Comment: @GregMcNulty good question, and the answer is that we don't. We are called to resist him, not cast him anywhere. dleyva3 is referring to Revelation 20:14 where God throws death and Hell into the lake of fire for final destruction during judgment day.

Comment: @GregMcNulty. Yes, Ben is right. Death should be capitalized in this instance.

Comment: Yes, as Death seems to be an anthropomorphism of the concept of death.